# Programming in C ++

Tags: c++

I want to program in C ++ what program do I use and how to load it?

I'm new to programming and I want to know which program is used to program it. I expect this is the first step for every programmer

Comment: I suggest you start with [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It will tell you about compilers and other useful tools.

Comment: I recommend you start by reading what [assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) is, then understand what a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) is, then understand the function of the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)), then look at the [list of languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) you can program in, pick up an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), then pick a [C++ project on GitHub](https://github.com/trending/c++) if you want to learn C++, and start making mistakes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it's easy to say I can't. Maybe do what you can to make Stackoverflow more welcoming and help this clueless guy.

Comment: @tomerzeitune Thank you for your high ethics (clueless!!!!)=)

Answer (score 1):

I you have lack of Bandwidth you can go with the [Microsoft Visual Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

this is very good alternative of lots of the editor.

for compiling your code use [minGW C++ compiler](http://www.mingw.org/category/wiki/download)

And a good tutorial reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need a text editor (notepad or notepad++) and a compiler.

I use Visual Studio 2017 (an IDE which has all this plus more built-in).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows then you can download code blocks or you can download Ubuntu terminal from Microsoft store.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac OS try with Xcode, it’s free and allows you to access a huge trough of tools. Personally C++ is an insane language to jump into immediately. To learn programming I suggest python until you grasp OOP, then move on into reading about what code actually is. Look into how hardware from cpu(registers and words) builds into psuedo software level like assembly, and eventually jump into the abstract principles. After this start simple with C, libraries and then move to C++. If you want to dive into C++ immediately then I suggest you look into memory management and pointer referencing, diff between stack and heap and ignore network level stuff until you have a good grasp on this.  It is easier for you to have an end goal other than “ I want to learn to program”, especially for tailored advice.

Answer (score 0):

For windows i would suggest a Microsoft product like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/vs/community/). Both are very good. If u want to have a nice and smooth start, I would prefer Visual Studio Community.

In my opinion there are countless other options for windows. Like

- [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

OR

- [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html)

All of them have a very active community.

From a starters point of view, I would suggest a product from Microsoft... Even if most people here would crucify me for that answer^^ But it is simple and easy to start. As beginner you should not worry about setting things up. You want to start smoothly and fast, so you can concentrate on learning C++, which is a hard task anyway.

There is also a hard way... you can use a plain text editor. Here I would suggest [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.6.3.html), which is the a kind of standard program. Then you have to get a compiler like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). If you have this working, you have to compile on console, which is not very starter friendly, so I would avoid that, if i were you.

For learning C++ I would suggest something like [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm). The online course is free and very well structured and explained. With the knowledge from there, you can take of in any direction =)

To understand what lies behind all that fancy nicely readable code, you can read through this [Tutorialspoint Assembly](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt use visual studio 2017 community 
 https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
Check out this video tutorial for windows
https://youtu.be/1OsGXuNA5cc (highly recommend)

Choose file -> new project -> empty cpp project. Create a new .cpp file in the solution explorer on your right. 
And use this code to get you going :

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
std::cout << "hello , world !" << std::endl;
}
}
```